# Integrating step function in R

Tags: r, integral

I have 2 functions whose integrals sum up to 1:

```
> body <- function(x) {dlnorm(x, meanlog=5.141287, sdlog=1.563058)}
> tail <- function(x) {16.11505*x**-1.752366}
> integrate(body, 1, 100)$value + integrate(tail, 100, 5002)$value
[1] 1
```

However, when I define a step function from the 2 functions, the integral of the step function doesn't equal to 1:

```
> double_pareto <- function(x) {if (x < 100) body(x) else tail(x)}
> integrate(double_pareto, 1, 5002)
1.074265 with absolute error < 3.6e-05
There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In if (x < 100) body(x) else tail(x) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why is that? what is the proper way to integrating a step function in R?

Comment: the if else should be vectorized `double_pareto <- function(x) {ifelse(x < 100, mybody(x), mytail(x))}`

Comment: You should read the help page for `if` more closely. It's unfortunate that the `ifelse` function is mentioned as a way to "control flow" since it's really a function, but it's also unfortunate that _you_ did not read that help page as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ifelse` function instead of `if` construct in defining `double_pareto` function does the trick:

```
> double_pareto <- function(x) {ifelse(x < 100, body(x), tail(x))}
> integrate(double_pareto, 1, 5002)$value
[1] 1.000004
```